# I have an sql error when performing UPDATE on my table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Eror Message

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 Cannot insert duplicate key row in
>   object 'dbo.RTU_ADDRESS' with unique index 'Unique Key RTU'. The
>   duplicate key value is (2, 5, 4, 6, 500, 610, IUY       ). The
>   statement has been terminated.

Script for Table

```
USE [hts]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[RTU_ADDRESS]    Script Date: 03/19/2013 21:07:19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RTU_ADDRESS](
    [RowNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StationId] [int] NULL,
    [SystemId] [int] NULL,
    [CCNumber] [int] NULL,
    [LineNumber] [int] NULL,
    [RTUNumber] [int] NULL,
    [SRTUNumber] [int] NULL,
    [Description] [char](100) NOT NULL,
    [SDescription] [char](100) NOT NULL,
    [Area_ID] [char](10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Script for Indexes

```
USE [hts]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [Unique Key RTU]    Script Date: 03/19/2013 21:08:31 ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Unique Key RTU] ON [dbo].[RTU_ADDRESS] 
(
    [StationId] ASC,
    [SystemId] ASC,
    [CCNumber] ASC,
    [LineNumber] ASC,
    [RTUNumber] ASC,
    [SRTUNumber] ASC,
    [Area_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

C# code:

```
SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = null;
                strSelectCmd = "SELECT RowNo FROM RTU_ADDRESS";
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
                sqlCmd.Connection = m_SqlConn;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = strSelectCmd;
                int i = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
                sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;


                strInsCmd = "UPDATE RTU_ADDRESS SET RTUNumber='" + rtunum.Text + "', SRTUNumber='" + srtunum.Text + "', Description='" + desc.Text + "', SDescription='" + sdesc.Text + "' WHERE Area_ID='" + area_ID.Text + "' AND StationId='" + station.Text + "' AND SystemId='" + sys.Text + "' AND CCNumber='" + ccnum.Text + "' AND LineNumber='" + linenum.Text + "'";

                strErrorMsg = Utilities.ExecuteSQLCommand(m_SqlConn, strInsCmd);
                string check = "duplicate";
                bool d = check.Any(strErrorMsg.Contains);
                if (d == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" Duplicates Entries Found", "Database Insertion");
                }
                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strErrorMsg) == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(this, "Error!Unable to Add New RTU Configurations!", "RTU Configurations error");
                }
                else
                {
                    d = false;
                    this.Close();
                }
```

I am now lost on what to do, I didn't put any duplicates.

I just want to update RTUNumber, SRTUNumber, Description, and SDescription while keeping my stationID,systemID,CCNumber,LineNumber and Area_ID constant. Please help

UPDATE:
Select statement

```
SELECT * FROM RTU_ADDRESS WHERE Area_ID='IUY ' AND StationId='2' AND SystemId='5' AND CCNumber='4' AND LineNumber='6'
```

give me 2 results but RTUNumber and SRTUNumber are different.

Please help

Comment: Forgive my ignorance here, but why have you got such a huge PK index in the first place?

Comment: RTUNumber, SRTUNumber are part of UNIQUE Index, you may be trying to update them to values that are already in that table and Errors don't lie :)

Comment: But I cannot change the unique index, so how shall I proceed from here?

Comment: I have a huge PK because it is the requirement that this number must be unique.

Comment: It'd be great if you used parameterized queries or a stored procedure so that you could avoid all this SQL injection prone ad-hoc SQL and so that your query could have carriage returns and indenting and be somewhat readable.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I have to wrie a code in C#, but if I create a stored procedure it is easier to do it in indexes... I wish to follow your advice.

Comment: A stored procedure doesn't help with indexes - it would just remove all this unreadable query code from your application code.

Comment: It will not help in my problem, thanks aaron

Comment: Can you guys please vote up my reputation... I can't post any question anymore if my reputation when down. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems pretty clear that the update you're trying to do will generate duplicate in your table. Have you tried doing a select on your table based on the values you're trying to use to update ? You'll most probably find an existing record...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the conditions in the where clause of your update statement you would get this error if there is more than record having the same AreaId, SystemId, StationId, CCNumber and LineNumber, because you are trying to update them with the same RTUNumber and SRTUNumber. You can check this by running this sql:

```
SELECT AreaId, SystemId, StationId, CCNumber, LineNumber, COUNT(*)
FROM RTU_ADDRESS
GROUP BY AreaId, SystemId, StationId, CCNumber, LineNumber
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If any rows are returned then you will get the "duplicate" error.

In fact your edited version says this is the case. Although the two records may have different SRTUNumbers and RTUNumbers you are trying to giving them the same SRTUNumber and RTUNUmber in the update statement.

Comment: Great and I have find my own answer too. I change the index to RTUNumber and SRTUNumber only which is unique and I think my problem is solved, just need to update my Boss tommorow and let him what he thinks.. THanks you are great young BOB.

Comment: The update will still give a duplicate error even with a unique index on just RTUNumber and SRTUNumber for the same reason.

Comment: Just to further explain...your update is assuming that the combination of AreaId, SystemId, StationId, CCNumber, LineNumber is unique. I think you need some extra conditions in your where clause.

Comment: No, because the update statement in your question will violate the unique index. At the end of your question you said the select statement returns 2 rows, so that means your update statement is trying to update both these rows with the SAME RTUNumber and SRTUNumber meaning that the 2 rows in question which were unique before the update would not be unique following the update.